# Is it possible to diagnose performance issues purely using unit tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, performance-testing

Is it possible to write unit tests in a framework like NUnit such that it checks if framework class library supplied objects (like RegularExpression) are initialised only once (or limited times) in application code?. 
Is it possible (and recommended) to have unit tests that enforce certain rules on object initialisation and its lifetime? For example in the code below -

```
class Utility{
    public bool IsGuide(string key){
        string strRegex = @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b";
        Regex guidRegEx = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        return guidRegEx.IsMatch(stringValue);    
    }
}
```

The code above is being called from a loop in page.aspx. Every time this page is being called due to large number of RegEx objects being initialised in memory performance hit is observed. The solution is to initialise the RegEx object as static class level instance.

To enforce that this code is not accidentally modified again it is possible to mock RegEx and check number of initialisations?

From 'semantics' view point I think that this type of control over design and implementation is overkill. Developer should know basics such as object types and their lifecycles. However I would like to know if there are known patterns/standard practices as such to address this kind of problem(s)?

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: [Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130305/is-it-a-good-idea-to-measure-the-performance-of-a-method-by-using-unit-test-time)

Comment: Not an answer, but the Regex isn't dynamic, so just make it a static readonly property of `Utility`, then it won't be possible to call it more than once: `class Utility { private static readonly Regex guidRegEx = new Regex(@"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);public bool IsGuide(string key){ return guidRegEx.IsMatch(key); } }`. Or just [`Guid.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) could be another option

Comment: @Rhumborl : Thanks! This is what we changed it to. We are exploring the possibility of putting a unit test that would break if nature of instantiation of the object is changed, i.e. if another developer walks in and changes the code from static initialisation to class level variable based initialisation, the test should break. Except Microsoft fakes there dosent seem to be any other mocking framework supporting class library function mocking. P.S. This is .net 3.5 so Guid.TryParse() is not available (but I got your point).

Comment: I think main purpose of tests to test behaviour of your software, where you will be able freely refactor implementations and then by running tests be sure that software still working properly. In your case you try to test implementation details, which makes your test fragile - you will end up to change tests every time you change implementations even when main behaviour remain same.

Comment: Introduce interface `GuideParser` with method `TryParse`, use implementation of this interface for parsing Guides.

Comment: @Fabio : Thanks for the suggestion! There was no intention to put a unit test to enforce 'static' nature of RegEx as explained above, however we started observing performance hit only after performance tests were run on integrated software. This was expensive in terms of efforts required to investigate it, besides we wanted to put a check so that developers do not accidentally modify the RegEx from static to class level variable in future. Intention was to have a first line of defence before such issues hit the performance environment.

Comment: As suggested by Rhumbori in his answer, this dosent look like a clean approach. It works but then it will create maintenance headache. Correct way to solve such behavioural issues is to address them through something like code analysis tools. In short, I agree with your statement that putting unit test for a purpose like this is going to result into fragile unit tests that will start breaking squeaking with frequent design changes. Besides, a developer should know the difference between instantiating RegEx in a loop vs. making it a statically spawned object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that a unit test isn't the way to go with this. You would need to create an abstraction around `Regex` purely for testing purposes, and also rely on developers to create an appropriate test. I think you would end up in a similar situation but with more confusing code.

As you want to enforce a coding standard, as such, I would instead look at creating [an analyser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn879356.aspx) or, if required, an [FxCop rule](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010/) which can check if a `Regex` is being instantiated inside a method. This could of course get complicated because there are no doubt situations where you *would* want to break this rule, but it seems a better fit solution to me and harder for developers to sidestep.